# Java - escape sequences lost

Tags: java, soap, escaping

I have problem with escape sequences in Java.
I'm calling one web service witch accepts some String arguments and one byte[ ] argument, and returns byte[ ].
When I receive that byte[ ], I write it to file and open that file with some of the text 
editors like Open Office.
Everything looks fine, but my \n and \t are replaced with space (" ").
People who used this web service before, said it will work if I replace my \n and \t with characters `&#xD;` and `&#xA;` but it still doesn't work.

I tried almost everything what I found on google to fix this, but still didn't fix it.
I still assume that web service is good, It's just up to me what will I send instead of my newline and tab characters, but I don't know is there any other character combination that will replace my \n and \t correctly.

It's very hard for me to ask right question here, because I cannot see the web service implementation.
Maybe the SOAP messages that I send does some conversion?
Or is there something else like :

`String replaceString = myString.replace("\\n", "&#xD;");`

Or I am doing it wrong ?

Edit :

The solution should look like this :

https://github.com/NetAngels/django-webodt/issues/10

But even that still didn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE : 
I'm sending one empty `openOffice .odf file (byte[])`, few String that contains username of logged user, etc. and one HashMap that contains all user inputs from text fields that I have on form. In that text fields, user often enter newline or tab, and when everything is merged via web service, the newline and tab are replaced with space. Web service is working good, I have full access to it. The return from web service method is byte[] witch represent filled .odt file.

Comment: Show us your code. If you receive bytes, you should directly write them to a file, without transforming anything to a String. A byte[] is for binary data.

Comment: I'm not transforming anything to a String when I receive byte[]. The Strings and byte[] that I send to web service, are somehow merged, but that merge doesn't append \n and \t well. So, I'm doing replace in Strings that I send.

Comment: That's a good thing, but you still don't show your code, so it's still not possible to find what could be wrong inside it.

Comment: Well, I don't have source code now, but I'll post it tomorrow. But whole point is that I have some Strings, and they contain escape characters, and then I call web service with those Strings as arguments and one byte[] argument. I'm trying with replace/replaceAll methods on that Strings to save my escape sequences, but still didn't success.

Comment: You may not have access to the web service, but you seem to have an idea of what it's supposed to be doing.  Can you please describe what you are sending to the web service, what you expect the returned byte array to contain, and what it actually contains?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that real problem is in the web service. The XML writer on web service is always doing an escaping of characters like `&, <, >` and etc. Instead of getting sequence `&#10;` or `&#13;` I get sequence `&amp;#10;` witch is not a newline character. These characters are shown when I open my .odt file, because of this `&amp;`, but when I manually replace them with original `&#10;` then they are now shown and newline appears.

I tried to put this `&#10;` in CDATA tag, but event CDATA's braces `<` and `>` are escaped with `&lt;` and `&gt;` So, even CDATA isn't interpreted correctly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`\\n` is wrong. You should use `\n`.
because the first is the caracter '\' followed by n and the second is the caracter
'\n' which is new line

Comment: Please add some explanation. You might also double check your formatting, I am not sure whether the answer is rendered as you intended it. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help